# remove substring from string by entering first and last character php

Tags: php, string

How can i remove substring from string by entering first and last character of substring in php

For example in string "Hello my name is John" if i enter 'n' and 's' it should return "Hello my  John"... Please Help

Comment: tried [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php) over [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php)?

Comment: What if the letters appear more than once in the string? Like `Hello my last name is Doe and my first name is John`. And what if only one of the two letters appear in the string?

Comment: You can use a regulare expression also, but why do you want to do it_

Comment: yes using regular expression with preg_replace works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Process function.
 * For lack of a better name.
 */
function process($f, $l, $subject)
{
    return preg_replace(sprintf('/%s.*?%s/', preg_quote($f), preg_quote($l)), '', $subject);
}

$f = 'n';
$l = 's';

echo process($f, $l, 'Hello my last name is Doe and my first name is John');
```

Output:

```
Hello my last  Doe at  John
```

I added utility, but it is effectively the same as `preg_replace('/n.*?s/', '', $subject)`.

Comment: it cuts the n of John, poor men :/

Comment: copy n paste mistake, fixed output.  still the worst function i have ever written though :S

Comment: i think i've tomatos on my eyes x.X in your replace, souldn't $n and $s be $f and $l? or i'm unable to read your code :\

Comment: yep, again, my lack of commitment to this terrible answer made me typo.  fixed that

Answer (score 1):

You should get the position of the first and second letter and use strpos for the method substr

```
function my_Cut($string, $first_letter, $second_letter){
   $pos[] = strpos($string, $first_letter);
   $pos[] = strpos($string, $second_letter);
   $result = substr($string, $pos[0] , -($pos[1]-$pos[0]-2)); 
   return str_replace ($result, "", $string);
 }

  $string = "Hello my name is John";
  echo my_Cut($string, "n", "s");
```

Something like this... I think.

Comment: Same thing as UnskilledFreak, [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) should be used with `$offset` parameter to avoid instances where `$second_letter` occurs before `$first_letter`.

Comment: You are right, thanks for your correction. Anyway I think my answer isn't correct (I can't test it now)

Answer (score 1):

with your string given:

```
$var = "Hello my name is John";

$sub = getSubString($var,"n","s");

echo $sub;

function getSubString($str,$start,$end) {

    if(($pos1=strpos($str,$start))===false)
        return $str; // not found


    if(($pos2=strpos($str,$end,$pos1))===false)
        return $str; // not found

    return substr($str,0,$pos1).substr($str,$pos2+1);
}
```

results in:

```
Hello my John
```

Comment: [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) has an offset parameter that should probably be used (in case second character is present before first ("sHello my name is John" would fail in your example).

Comment: Not a problem. Figure you already had a 90% bid in, i'll let you and Marta get the rep points.